# R Markdown syntax errors crash R Studio when `blogdown::serve_site()` is live and I `Ctrl-S`

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown

I can serve a local blogdown instance with `blogdown::serve_site()` and any and all saves with `Ctrl-S` are automatically pushed to my browser. Live updating. It's pretty cool.

But if I make an error in my .Rmd syntax (happens a lot) and I save `Ctrl-S`, my console informs me of the error, and R Studio hangs. I just kill R Studio from my Linux terminal and start over again. A little bit of a pain.

It makes sense that the system can't push my latest updates to my browser because there's an .Rmd error, but shouldn't R Studio kill the `blogdown::serve_site()` process at this point? I'm using the latest R Studio preview version and have updated packages via `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` and `tinytex::tlmgr_update()`.

What's the best workflow to live update blogdown without having to worry about unknown .Rmd errors causing R Studio to hang?

---

#### xfun::session_info('blogdown')

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, RStudio 1.2.1335

Locale:
  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8      
  LC_NUMERIC=C              
  LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
  LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
  LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
  LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
  LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
  LC_NAME=C                 
  LC_ADDRESS=C              
  LC_TELEPHONE=C            
  LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
  LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 BH_1.69.0.1     blogdown_0.11  
  bookdown_0.9    digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.13  
  glue_1.3.1      graphics_3.5.3  grDevices_3.5.3
  highr_0.8       htmltools_0.3.6 httpuv_1.5.1   
  jsonlite_1.6    knitr_1.22      later_0.8.0    
  magrittr_1.5    markdown_0.9    methods_3.5.3  
  mime_0.6        promises_1.0.1  R6_2.4.0       
  Rcpp_1.0.1      rlang_0.3.4     rmarkdown_1.12 
  servr_0.13      stats_3.5.3     stringi_1.4.3  
  stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.11    tools_3.5.3    
  utils_3.5.3     xfun_0.6        yaml_2.2.0
```

Comment: You can do a `try catch` maybe

Comment: `blogdown::serve_site()` should pause when there is an error in your Rmd, if you are using the latest versions of all packages as you claimed. Actually there is no need to claim it---please just provide `xfun::session_info('blogdown')`.

Comment: @Yihui Xie I can provide `session_info()` when I'm back at home in front of Linux box. The 'pause' is the problem. The 'pause' never ends, and I'm never dropped to console in R Studio. This is while `blogdown::serve_site()` is active, and I do a `Ctrl-S` after inputting an .Rmd syntax error. Perhaps I'm not waiting long enough during the pause (I've waited ~5 min before killing R Studio, seems excessive)?

Comment: By "pause" I mean it will pause until you fix the error and save the Rmd file again. As long as the Rmd file is not re-saved, `blogdown::serve_site()` will just wait and do nothing.

Comment: I am allowed to fix the error (edit the .Rmd) but I can't save with `Ctrl-S`, neither can I save by clicking the disk icon. Nothing happens. If I try to close R with the `x` it asks if I want to save. I can choose either "Don't", "Cancel", or "Save" and it's like I'm hitting a dummy button. Nothing happens. I'll just run chunks with `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` before I `Ctrl-S` to eliminate this problem from my workflow. Thanks for the assistance.